# how to know the cell , face information of a 2D mesh

Tags: cgal

I generate a 2D mesh with CGAL. 
   But how to run through all the faces , cells in the mesh so as to start my FVM computations. 
    Regards

Answer (score 0):

A 2D mesh is stored inside a 2D constrained Delaunay Triangulation. To get all the range of all faces, use [`cdt.finite_faces_begin()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html#a7518217f58b97866b6010996e8ca4895) and `cdt.finite_faces_end()`. This will gives you all the faces (even those outside of the meshed domain). Use [`face_handle->is_in_domain()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classDelaunayMeshFaceBase__2.html#a438ba4b035f8fcc7732565050aea2acf) to select only the faces inside the domain.